# Retrieve/iterate Redmine wiki content and return it?

Tags: ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm trying to achieve a simple plugin that takes the current wiki page content and matches/replaces everytime a word occurs via regular expression/ The regular expression part itself is easy, I'm more interested in how to retrieve/iterate the wiki content and return it after replacing. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a plugin, I'm sure you know their source is available on [github](https://github.com/edavis10/redmine), 
and if you check that out you can use the models they already provide. I haven't tested, but it looks like if you:

```
require "#{path_to_redmine_source}/app/models/wiki_content"
WikiContent.all.each do |post|
  post.text.gsub!(/important_data/, "nonsense")
  post.save!
end
```

that should work, and it will use whatever adapter's redmine already has configured. It will, however, require loading all the plugins that redmine uses, which could suck.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that! For me it's not a problem that it loads all the plugins, I can look into that later. I've been trying to get it to work by inserting important_data in the wiki and using the following code: http://paste.enzotools.org/show/1500/ - it doesn't work for me, do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks! Dennis

Comment: Once again I haven't tested, but I edited my post and think it might work better. I took out the post.text =, and added a ! to post.save, which will raise and error if things go wrong. Hope that helps.